# A colorful Connect Wall you can almost taste

Tags: word, knowledge, pattern, connect-wall

The 16 prompts below may be separated into 4 groups.
Additionally, there is a word absent from the wall which may be placed in all four of those groups.

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **#F0F8FF** | **(240, 100%, 50%)** | **(255, 215, 0)** | **Aqua** |
| **(250, 235, 215)** | **Lime** | **#000000** | **(0, 100%, 25%)** |
| **(39, 85%, 95%)** | **(230, 230, 250)** | **Orchid** | **#FA8072** |
| **SlateBlue** | **#EE82EE** | **(39, 77%, 83%)** | **(64, 224, 208)** |

**Can you identify the four groups?**
**What new word can be placed in all four of those groups?**

**Author note:** You *can* try to have the groups be what they look like, but it won't help at all for the final word. (X, Y%, Z%) are in HSL.

Hints:

> SlateBlue is a very peculiar name, one amongst 140 others.

> One of the groups has an edgy side.

> One of the groups has a similar head and tail.

> One of the groups was inspired by nature.

Comment: It seems these are all colours of some sort...

Comment: Can you tell us, whether the values with percentages are hsl or hwb?

Comment: Any suggestions for which site to use for conversion? I get different names for some of them depending on which site I use.

Comment: In case this helps save anyone some time, using [this site](https://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_picker.asp) the 16 names are: rot13(NyvprOyhr, Oyhr, Tbyq, Ndhn, NagvdhrJuvgr, Yvzr, Oynpx, Znebba, ByqYnpr, Yniraqre, Bepuvq, Fnyzba, FyngrOyhr, Ivbyrg, Jurng, Ghedhbvfr)

Comment: Are you able to confirm if the grid contents are as I've identified in the comment above^? I've had three groups that match your 3 hints for quite a while now - it's the other one that's proving elusive (or so it seems - it could be that my interpretation of your third spoiler is slightly wonky) and at this stage I don't know if it's because I've got one of them wrongly identified or if I'm just not thinking along the right lines... I suspect knowing if the list is correct would help others too, not just me... Thanks!

Comment: @Stiv Mhm, the contents are correct, I believe the second part of the first hint can't refer to any other groups or colors (or at least I hope so).

Comment: @Stiv Your list was indeed useful, so thanks for that. (For what it's worth, I have several criteria, but they seem to apply to the same set of items and I haven't got anything to account for the second and fourth items in the last column. I want the missing item to be `#FFA500`, but that's probably wishful thinking.)

Comment: @MOehm My current thinking is that it's either that one or #808000 - I think we're going along the same lines here...

Comment: Oh, yes, that also fits my theory, except perhaps a certain dark pattern that I found.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first thing to note ...

> ... (and which several commenters noted early on) is that all items on the wall define [X11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X11_color_names) or [Web colours](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_colors). (Both sets are similar, but (0, 100%, 25%) is not a named X11 colour; as a Web colour, it's maroon. But the X11 wiki page has a better tabular overview, so I linked that, too.)
>
>  Stiv has helpfully identified all 16 colours:
>
> ```
>     Alice Blue          Blue            Gold            Aqua
>     Antique White       Lime            Black           Maroon
>     Old Lace            Lavender        Orchid          Salmon
>     Slate Blue          Violet          Wheat           Turquoise
> ```

The four groups:

> Groups in Connect Walls can overlap, but there must be four items in four different groups. Ideas for the groups:
>
>  (1) Colours that also have a Dark variant: Dark **Blue**, Dark **Orchid**, Dark **Salmon**, Dark **Slate Blue**, Dark **Turquoise** and Dark **Violet** are valid Web colour names. The "edgy side" mentioned in the hint is a dark side.
>
>  (2) Colours that are named after plants: **Lime**, **Lavender**, **Orchid**, **Violet**, **Wheat**. (Arguably this is the group that is "inspired by nature")
>
>  (3) Colours where at least one of their RGB components is zero: **Blue** (#0000FF), **Lime** (#00FF00), **Gold** (#FFD700), **Aqua** (#00FFFF), **Black** (#000000) and **Maroon** (#800000).
>
>  (4) Colours whose names begin and end with a vowel: **Alice Blue**, **Aqua**, **Antique White** and **Old Lace**. I think this is the group that has "has a similar head and tail".

Sorting it out:

> The overlap can be sorted out:
>
>  (1) Dark colours: Blue, Salmon, Slate Blue, Turquoise
>  (2) Plants: Lavender, Orchid, Violet, Wheat
>  (3) Zero RGB: Gold, Lime, Black, Maroon
>  (4) Vowels: Alice Blue, Aqua, Antique White, Old Lace

The missing word:

> I think the missing word is **Orange**, which is the name of the Web colour #FFA500: Dark Orange is a Web colour name; an orange (tree) is a plant; the blue component is zero and it starts and ends with a vowel.
>
>  (In a comment, Stiv suggests **Olive** (#808000), which also fits, except that the corresponding dark colour is called Dark Olive *Green*, not just Dark Olive.)

Comment: With some leeway Maroon could fit into 2. (marron, chestnut, and [this random page](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Colors_named_after_plants) agrees)

Comment: Yeah, maybe. And then move something else from group (2) to (3)? I mean, _qua_ isn't so hot as English word compared to the others. Remove more than one letter at the front to get "vender" (ugh!) or "chid"?

Comment: Groups 1 and 4 are correct, Group 2 has one of its member missing/switched with another, and Group 3's definition is sadly not true. Gur rqtl fvqr vf vzcyl n "qnex" fvqr gurl unir, gur zvffvat tebhc qbrfa'g pbeerfcbaq gb nal uvag. Lbh qvq trg fbzrjung pybfr sbe pbzcyrgrarff fnxr :)

Comment: Well done for persevering - my way of thinking was more aligned with your first attempt minus the 'dark' group, so I was actually two groups off in the end +1